# Flutter Web Stuck at initial loading screen

Tags: flutter, flutter-web

I am running flutter web on chrome from Android Studio. It was running fine. Suddenly when I run again, it is stuck on the initial loading screen. It doesn't route to the expected page I have set. It is stuck on the white screen and doesn't show anything on console except this -

```
Debug service listening on ws://127.0.0.1:60303/LwKMap73SGc=/ws

 Running with sound null safety 
Debug service listening on ws://127.0.0.1:60303/LwKMap73SGc=/ws
Flutter Web Bootstrap: Auto
```

But the same project is working fine on Android and iOS.
I have attached my flutter doctor output below -

```
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.0.1, on macOS 12.4 21F79 darwin-arm, locale en-US)
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 32.1.0-rc1)
[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 13.4)
[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
[✓] Android Studio (version 2021.2)
[✓] IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate Edition (version 2022.1.1)
[✓] VS Code (version 1.67.2)
[✓] Connected device (3 available)
[✓] HTTP Host Availability
```

Cannot find any solution on stack or github.

Comment: Was able to run with this command ```flutter run -d chrome --web-renderer html```

Answer (score 1):

Try with `flutter clean` and build again
If you still encounter problems with Chrome try with Edge

And if I remember exactly there was a problem with web introduced before (unfortunately I don't know it was resolved) looks similar like yours.
For me sometimes helped just clicking on Chrome window.

Comment: Just run flutter pub get after flutter clean Command.